# On the meaning of そんなの秒で

Tags: meaning, phrases

So, i was reading a podcast script and came across this sentence :

> はい、何に四苦八苦しています?　そんなの秒で答えられます。　コロナです

Does `そんなの秒で答えられます` mean something along the lines of i will answer you in a second ?

Answer (score 4):

- そんなの is "something like that", "such a thing", or in this context, "such a question". (に)は has been omitted after it.
- 秒で is a recent *slangy* adverb meaning "in a second" or "instantly". Use with caution.
- 答えられます is the (polite) potential form of 答える.

> そんなの秒で答えられます。
>   I can answer such a question instantly.